# JS variable reproduce and modify

Tags: javascript, arrays

I declare a variable say 'bubble' and then I assign it a value of another variable say 'gum', and after I try to change the 'bubble' array 'gum' array also changes. why does this happen, how can I manage to change bubble and not gum

```
let bubble= this.gum
bubble.shift()
```

after this gum also shift

Comment: look at pointers...

Comment: I don't see any bubbles in your example! please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: and where comes the `this` ?

Comment: I use nuxt. I declared gum in nuxt data, so i can access it through this

Comment: cause it's he same ref, you need to deep copy the array. for example: `let bubble = this.gum.slice()`

Comment: is still not reproducible. PLEASE READ https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: careful the `slice` is a shallow copy. If you have objects and you modify the object it will be modified in the first array too

Comment: for details cf this good article https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089

Comment: well. thank you all. and Mjojo I dont know how to share my code to be readable here, its more thank 1000 lines. I dont know how to reproduce this sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your variable immutable, both gums and bubbles will share the same array after doing a shallow copy

```
    const gums = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const bubbles = gums;
    gums.push(5);
    console.log(gums, bubbles)
```

Make bubbles immutable

```
const bubbles = [...gums];
```

Comment: so if I had used const instead of let, it would have worked even if those are same ref?

Comment: no it would not, you need to make a deep copy of your gums array and then assign it to bubbles, let and const impact scoping but not mutation

Comment: using "const bubbles = [...gums];" solved my problem